# Shall we make a bean and Autowire OkHttpClient

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "q=609&client=122&layer=explore&key=w3S4BEmDKd8Q3VCCO2OZTnI8sAQxIFwA&name=utkarsh%20sharma&password=utk&phone=1111111112");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://explore-uat.mapmyindia.in/explore-api/v1.3/")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
  .addHeader("Postman-Token", "44666246-b697-488f-9410-df09f7faa53a")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

I'am using this code to make a post request to API.
I use this many times in my class.
Is it possible to make a bean of OKhttpClient and autowire in my class

Please reply!!Thnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would declare it as Spring bean, since that makes it much easier for testing compared to a Singleton solution. However, since you are using Spring boot, you could also just use `RestTemplate`, as described here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

Comment: Plus, I think you can tell RestTemplate to use OkHttpClient in the background - if you're using any settings for pooling or whatnot already, and need to chosse this specific client.

Comment: That's basically true, but you can only use http clients implementing `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`, which I think OkHttpClient is not doing

Comment: Well, there is this org.springframework.http.client.OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory, which is used by RestTemplate; I'd guess, that you just have to include OkHttpclient in your maven dependencies, and it'd be picked up.  As per "org.apache...": Definitely not so, this is all wrapped in springs own ClientHttpRequest.

Comment: Ah ok sorry, I did not look at the factory itself. Then you are right of course

Answer (score 5):

You could do it by declaring a bean somewhere in your configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class HttpClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public OkHttpClient httpClient() {
        return new OkHttpClient();
    }
}
```

Also, if not declared otherwise, every spring bean is by default a singleton: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html

Regarding the initial question. I think you should declare it as a spring bean. It should ease testing.

Answer (score 0):

A singleton as defined below should be sufficient:

```
public class OkHttpFactory {

    private static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public OkHttpClient getClient() {
        return client;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your singleton is simple and eager. If the instantiation of OkkHttClient is heavy you create it asap.